# What is the most popular program to write a web application to run on IIS?

Tags: iis, web-applications

Is it Visual Studio? What version is better/easier to use for that? And what programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends too much on the language. It's probably Visual Studio, if you're doing ASP / ASP.NET, and if you're using IIS, you probably are. However, for other languages (PHP, Perl etc) a lot of IDEs are used. In my university we do use a lot of Eclipse, properly plugin-ed for Web Dev'in in PHP, and the Play! Framework for Java. Also CGI for C/C++.

Hope it helps!